# How to reference .Net standard in T4 file?

Tags: .net, t4, .net-standard

I have a .Net standard 2.0 library. In this library I have a T4 file. The file contains these rows.

```
<#
            foreach (MessageType enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MessageType)))
            {
                var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(MessageType), enumValue);
#>
```

I get the following error in Visual Studio.

> Compiling transformation: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

How can I add a reference to 'netstandard'?

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, you can use

```
<#@ assembly name="NetStandard" #>
```

Comment: It does not work anymore for the moment. Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue.
I've solved this with adding reference inside t4 to file on disk

```
<#@ assembly Name="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netstandard.dll" #>
```

if You don't have that file try to find **netstandard.dll** inside directory **"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk"**

Answer (score 4):

This became an issue for us in the last few days. In addition we needed a solution that would work on all dev machines and all build machines.

So basically we copied the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netstandard.dll` file (and a couple of other standard files we needed) into a TTLibs folder under the solution.

Then we made the references in the TT *solution-relative* like this:
`<#@ assembly Name="$(SolutionDir)TTLib\netstandard.dll" #>`